# Default TTL value is not getting overridden

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching

I have created a cache in spring with the following configuration:

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"     p:cacheManager-ref="ehcache" />

<bean id="getBooksCache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean" p:cacheName="getBooks" p:overflowToDisk="false">
<property name="cacheManager">
<value>#{cacheManager.cacheManager}</value>
</property>
<property name="timeToLive" value="3000" />
</bean>
```

Even though the timeToLive is set to 3000s it is expiring in 120s which is the default TTL.

Any idea why the default value is not getting over-ridden?

Comment: I guess you don't have the same typo in the code as you have in your question. (property name="....  ; the opening < is missing!)

Comment: No. I didn't have that typo in my code. The problem was the timeToIdle was set to 120s by default. And that was clearing the cache every 2 mins.